# Mysql error on capistrano deploy

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to deploy a rails app with Capistrano but getting the following error:

**Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'mysqluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

If I ssh onto the server and user the same details as in my database.yml file, I can access mysql.  Is there any reason why cap should be any different?

It always happens at:

**executing locally: "rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile"**

Comment: Are you trying to connect with production mysql parameters, no development?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried this but it didn't solve.  It did however make me look at the error slightly differently.  I completely bypassed the executing locally.  I was checking my remote settings.  I don't have the prod server locally though... I created an blank one to get passed the issue.  Not perfect but works!